# My MERN Application shows error when deployed to heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern, http-status-code-503, dotenv

When trying to deploy my application to heroku the build succeeds but there is an error in the backend route `HLRoute` dealing with `dotenv` I'm not sure what the problem could be?[image]

[image]

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const path = require("path")
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser")


//MIDDLEWARE
app.use(cors())






// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//App Routes files

const houseRouter = require('./Routes/HouseListing/HLRoute')
const houseFetchRoute = require('./Routes/HouseFetchRoutes/HouseFetch')





//App route
app.use(houseRouter)
app.use(houseFetchRoute)


if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))

    app.get("*", (req, res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
} else {
    app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
        res.send("api running")
    })
}


//server entry point
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is runnning on port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

HLRoute.js

```
// const express = require('express')
// const router = express.Router()
const router = require('express').Router();
const {House} = require('../../Models/House');
const Formidable = require('formidable');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// require("dotenv").config()
// const { request, response } = require('express');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();


//mongoDB and Cloudinary

const mongoURI = process.env.Mongo_URI;

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
})


mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}, (error)=>{
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }
    return console.log("database is connected")
})

router.post("/api/house-listing", async (request, response)=>{
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(request, (error, fields, files)=>{
        const {
            price,
            city,
            county,
            numOfBeds,
            numOfBaths,
            numOfGarages,
            isSaleOrRent,
        } = fields

        const { house_image } = files;

        console.log('Price: ', price)
        console.log('City: ', city)
        console.log('county: ', county)
        console.log('numOfGarages: ', numOfGarages)
        console.log('numOfBeds: ', numOfBeds)
        console.log('numOfBaths: ', numOfBaths)
        console.log('isSaleOrRent: ', isSaleOrRent)
        console.log('houseImage', house_image.path)

        cloudinary.uploader.upload( house_image.path, 
            {folder:"/houseAgency/houses"}, async(error, result)=>{
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            const image_url = result.url;

            const newHouse = new House({
                house_location: {
                    
                    county: county,
                    city: city,

                },

                house_details: {
                    price: price,
                    numOfBeds: numOfBeds,
                    numOfBaths: numOfBaths,
                    numOfGarages: numOfGarages,
                    isSaleOrRent: isSaleOrRent,
                    house_image: image_url,
                }
            })
            const savedHouse = await newHouse.save();
            return response.status(200).json(savedHouse)
        })
    })
})



module.exports = router;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "real-estate-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client npm run build --prefix client",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.13",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: share your package.json file

Comment: I edited the original post, it is at the bottom.

Comment: if I am not wrong, dotenv should be a dependency and not a dev dependency

Comment: I tried to switch it over but that did not work.